# Remain selected year-month in datepicker UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hello:) Isn't datepicker save selected **year-month** data? I know it's possible in case of **yyMMdd** date format. My question is how about **yyMM** date format.

I want to save date data when I click 'done' button. So when click calendar button again, then I want to get selected date on datepicker UI.

As you can see in snippet, I'm not using date part. When you click year, month and done button, you can see select date in textfield. But When you click calendar button again, datepicker UI date shows today date again. How can I show date I selected?

```js
$("#mydate").datepicker({
   changeYear: true,
   changeMonth: true,
   setDate: new Date(),
   showButtonPanel: true,
   showOn: "button",
            showMonthAfterYear: true,
   monthNamesShort: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
   onChangeMonthYear: function (dateText) {
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
   },
   dateFormat: 'yy-MM',
   altField: "#mydate"
  });
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="text" id="mydate" />
```